# KendoUI gauge max value

Tags: kendo-ui, gauge

How can I set for Kendo UI Radial Gauge dynamic max number for pointer, if value for input field is higer than number of pointer:

```
<input id="gauge-value" value="180">

$(".gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
                        pointer: {
                            value: $("#gauge-value").val(),
                            color: "#000"
                        },
                        scale: {
                        minorUnit: 5,
                        startAngle: -30,
                        endAngle: 210,
                        max: 100
                    }
                    });
```

Comment: You could always just check `$("#gauge-value").val()` **before** rendering the gauge, and set a higher maximum if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Define `max` as an expression.

Example: if you want it to be 100 or `value` if it is more than 100, use:

```
$(".gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
    pointer: {
        value: $("#gauge-value").val(),
        color: "#000"
    },
    scale  : {
        minorUnit : 5,
        startAngle: -30,
        endAngle  : 210,
        max       : Math.max(100, $("#gauge-value").val())
    }
});
```